# How do I convert Blob Image to Bitmap Image in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, blob

I want to convert Blob Image to base64 - but I am not sure how can I achieve that

HTML Element

```
<img src="blob:https://sample.cloud.co.uk/b636a5fd-b3ee-45de-9314-1f20b006d3b4" alt="" style="max-width: 600px; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; max-height: 600px;">
```

Can someone please help me to get the bitmap or base64 image

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Try to read src attribute of img tag like this :

```
var pictureNode = webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("FOO_SELECTOR"));
    
var pictureURI = pictureNode.GetAttribute("src");
```

then download image as byte array and save it in BMP or JPEG Format :

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) 
{
    byte [] data = webClient.DownloadData(pictureURI);

   using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data)) 
   {
       using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem)) 
       { 
          // If you want it as Png
           yourImage.Save("path_to_your_file.png", ImageFormat.Png) ; 

          // If you want it as Jpeg
           yourImage.Save("path_to_your_file.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg) ; 
       }
   } 

}
```